# jQuery document.ready not firing (have included jq)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, after traversing google and Stack Overflow for a short while, most resources I found were people incorrectly including jQuery, which I included correctly.

I have this in my header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title>
  <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
</title>
<link href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {   
  alert("Hey");
  });
}
  alert("hello");
```

And everything else I need in there. When I take out the document ready, it alerts hello, however with the doc ready it doesn't alert either. I have never had this problem before with jQuery.

Comment: Typo. There is an extra `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error :) Try this!

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  alert("Hey");
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you! Cant believe I missed that! I will accept answer as soon as it lets me :)

Answer (score 3):

I see an extra curly brace in your code.  Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  alert("Hey");
  });
//} Remove this brace
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra bracket right below your alert("Hey") that is causing an error. Remove that bracket and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Change the second `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script>`

Replace `$(document).ready(function()` with `$(function ()`

Take out the extra `}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    //code  goes here
    alert("Hey");
});
```

It will work so you should place your code inside ready function.